# Python - Fast search for modified files in multiple folders

Tags: python, file, filesystems, last-modified

I am looking for an efficient implementation for finding modified files in multiple directories.

I do know that I can just recursively go through all those directories and check the modified date of those files I wanna check. This is quite trivial.

But what if I have a complex folder structure with many files in it? The upper approach won't really scale and might take up several minutes.

Is there a better approach to probe for modifications? Like is there something like a checksum on folders that I could use to narrow down the number of folders I have to check for modifications or anything like that?

A second step to my problem is also finding newly created files.

I am looking for a python based solution which is windows compatible

Comment: It seems to me that you have to check each file, unless the OS does it for you (automatically keep track of the last modifications for each folder?).

Comment: I can't think of a better method off the top of my head. To recursively check file mod times, you could use a combination of `os.walk(dir)` and `os.path.getmtime(file)`